# Download the artifact from bamboo using wget

Tags: bamboo

I am using wget to download bamboo artifact using the below command,

```
wget --http-user='userName' --http-password='*****' 'http://localhost/rest/api/latest/plan/AP-BAF/artifact?os_authType=basic' --no-check-certificate

where AP-BAF is the build plan and that plan has two stages and each stage produce artifacts.I want to download these two artifacts.

When I enter this command in command prompt,it shows the below output,

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><artifacts expand="artifa
cts"><link href="http://localhost/rest/api/latest/plan/AP-BAF
/artifact" rel="self"/><artifacts start-index="0" max-result="0" size="0"/></art
ifacts>

When i browse through bamboo and I can see the artifacts produced by the build.

Please help me as this is the high priority.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using os_username and os_password in the parameters.  See https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-7259 for details.

```
wget --save-cookies cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --no-check-certificate https://bamboo/userlogin\!default.action\?os_destination=%2Fstart.action\&os_username=myusername\&os_password=*****\&os_cookie=true
```